# Cannot Read Write NFC C# using library

Tags: c#, nfc

i have a coursework about nfc read and write, but i'm still new using C# and i found some libraries about nfc c#. one of them from [h4kbas](https://github.com/h4kbas/NfcReader) which I'm currenly using righ now.

the first thing i try is how to read UID, but it seem work fine

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NFC.Connect())
            {
                textBox1.Text = NFC.GetCardUID();
            }
        }
```

and then i try making read and write :

Read

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NFC.Connect())
            {
                NFC.WriteBlock(textBox2.Text, "5");
                //Close();
            }

        }
```

Write

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NFC.Connect())
            {
                NFC.ReadBlock("5");

                //Close();
            }
        }
```

but after i try making a read and write function above, i don't found any error massage but if i try read or write some string data on running process, forced to close and give massage "**The program '[10192] WFANFCReadWriteExecute.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).**" still..., i don't know the problem is on my code or i have to use "AuthBlock" first.

Comment: have you attempted to use a try/catch block to try and find a specific exception, and log it?

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture data and see what is failing.

Comment: @ADyson i was try that method as well. but it seems still not work

Comment: @jdweng i still not make onto data server, and i try making Windows Form App. it seems the problem lies on the code

Comment: What type of NFC card you using (Make and Model)? as that library is only designed to work with Type 4 cards and won't work with Type 1,2,3,5 and Mifare Classic.

Comment: @Andrew i am currenly using ACR122U and Mifare 1k card

Comment: It is using the smart card (https://github.com/h4kbas/NfcReader/blob/master/Card.cs).  Can you read/write card without application?   Try read card and then retry the application.  You need to unlock the card and reading from operating system will unlock card.  If it works after reading from operating system you need to add code to unlock card.

Comment: @jdweng i try read/write using 3rd party software or demo from acr122u is seems work in both my pc and my phone.. idk about how to unlock card, but it seems have something to do with NFC.AuthBlock.

Comment: Ok right type of commands are being sent as library are using the PICC Commands of the reader to talk to the Mifare Classic

Comment: @Andrew so it is some thing like convert string code from byte and the opposite?

Comment: Unlock and authorization are same thing.  Most card once you turn on machine and unlock the card stay unlocked.  So after using card can you run your c# without errors?

Comment: @jdweng yes, it seems now i can read/write normaly after unlocking the card. thx for the advice